# Mount Linux USB drive via WSL2

Tags: external-hard-drive, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ext4

I'm following [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) from Microsoft describing how to mount an external Linux drive via WSL2.

I have `10.0.20279 N/A Build 20279` on an ARM64 machine. I inspect the available drives with this command:

```
wmic diskdrive list brief
```

From there, I try to mount the drive:

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare
```

However, Windows complains:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

The drive has one `ext4` partition. I've also tried

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare --partition 1
```

which yields the same result. Any idea what's going on? I'm googling in vain right now...

Comment: I don't have the setup needed to attempt to reproduce this (neither ARM nor Insider/Preview), but I don't see any obvious mistakes in your process as compared to the Microsoft guide.

Comment: You're farather than i am.  All I get is `Invalid command line option: --mount` ... I know i'm running wsl2.